# Animation in FMX main thread stops when worker thread starts

Tags: multithreading, rest, delphi, firemonkey

My FireMonkey app has a save button that does this:

```
procedure TFormProductionRuns.buSaveFinishProductClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowActivity;
  ITask(TTask.Create(
    procedure
    begin
      try
        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            PostFinishProduct;
          end);
      finally
        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            HideActivity;
          end);
      end;
    end)).Start;
end;
```

The activity methods are defined as:

```
procedure TFormProductionRuns.ShowActivity;
begin
  frProgress1.ShowActivity;
end;

procedure TFormProductionRuns.HideActivity;
begin
  frProgress1.HideActivity;
end;

procedure TfrProgress.ShowActivity;
begin
  Self.Visible := True;
  ProgFloatAnimation.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TfrProgress.HideActivity;
begin
  ProgFloatAnimation.Enabled := False;
  Self.Visible := False;
end;
```

The frame is set to align content, so fills up the entire app screen when visible, and contains a "busy" animation. The bulk of the work is a REST request to a post web method.

```
procedure TFormProductionRuns.PostFinishProduct;
var
  AList: TObjectList<TFinishedProduct>;
  sReqBody, sResponse: String;
begin

  ...

  sReqBody := TJSONUtils.ObjectsToJSONArray<TFinishedProduct>(AList).ToString;
  RESTReqPostTransaction.Params.ParameterByName('ReqBody').Value := sReqBody;

  RESTClient1.Params.ParameterByName('host_port').Value := FLoginInfo.Server + ':' + FLoginInfo.Port;
  HTTPBasicAuthenticator1.Username := FLoginInfo.LoginId;
  HTTPBasicAuthenticator1.Password := FLoginInfo.LoginPw;
  
  try
    RESTReqPostTransaction.Execute;
  except on E:Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage('Post Finish Product failed. Exception: ' + E.Message);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  sResponse := RESTResponseFromPost.Content;

  ...

end;
```

What I'm finding is that the animation stops while this request is being processed, but my understanding was that the main thread would continue while the worker thread was waiting for the response.

The app does have a similar method that uses a **Get** REST request rather than **Post**, and that has no problems animating the "busy" graphic while the worker thread is waiting for the response.

Comment: Using Synchronize around the calls means you may as well not be using threads. Only do Synchronize if it is necessary AFTER the work is done to pass the results back.

Comment: The `TTask` is doing ALL of its work in the main thread, so of course the animations are going to be blocked. Don't use `Synchronize()` to run the `TTask`'s operations. Use it only when accessing shared resources, UI controls, etc, or to send notifications/updates back to the main thread (in that latter case, consider using `TThread.Queue()` instead).

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answer. The coding I did was based on the Healthcare Industry Template FireMonkey project supplied by Embarcadero. I will look into implementing the process a different way, where I still want to wait for the REST request to complete before allowing the user to do anything else, but I don't want to stop the main thread from doing the animations.

Answer (score 3):

TThread.Synchronize is a method which request execution by the main thread of the method passed in synchronize argument. This actually completely defeat multi-threading.

You have to design you thread so that synchronize is only use for very short actions such as updating the user interface or pass data between the worker thread and main thread because when synchronize is called, the thread is waiting (It is stopped) for the method passed in argument to be executed by the main thread. And while the main thread execute that method, it doesn't do anything else (And you animation stop).